# Groovy Postbuild do not execute scripts on Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've written simple groovy script, but I don't know how to execute it on Jenkins.

Look at this simple script:

```
String jbN = System.getenv('JOB_NAME')
println  jbN
println "Hello"
```

I would except that I will reveived at least "Hello". Script give no return. I've just received `Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure(or success)`

It seems that script is not executed.

EDIT:

I didn't add it, but I have already script which will analize logs, so I need it to execute it post-build. 
The problem is bigger then I thought. Plugins: "Scriptler" or "Groovy Plugin" do not print anything. 
Script which I'm trying to print out:

```
String jbN = System.getenv('JOB_NAME')
println  jbN
```

Comment: i see same problem. Any solutions?

Comment: Yes. Look at the answer.

Comment: this is tricky to debug! manager.listner.logger.println("TEST DEBUG") answer below saves the day.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution:

Script was executed but wasn't printed to console output.
To print result to console output you need to write: 
**`manager.listener.logger.println("Some string")`** instead of `println`.

To make it shorter do:

`logger = manager.listener.logger.&println
 // and call like this:
 logger("test log message")`

EDIT: add in logger example and to describe how to get env vars (and how to not get them) and to hopefully save people some debugging time . . . this is simple but awkward stuff.

**To get the workspace you can go through the manager object. Like this:**

`manager.build.workspace`

**To get env vars**, this **does not work**:

`String jbN = System.getenv('JOB_NAME')`

It shows jbN is null.
That makes sense as JOB_NAME is not an actual system environment var.

This also **does not work** to get env vars, an exception is thrown:

`${manager.envVars['WORKSPACE']}`

**This does work to get jenkins job "env vars" like WORKSPACE, JOB_NAME, BUILD_NAME:**

**`def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
 workspace = build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]`**

Example of use, you can call a groovy script in workspace like this:

`evaluate(new File(manager.build.workspace.toString() + "/dirinworkspace/scriptname.groovy"))`

Comment: It has already been added to docs at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to use the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) rather than the [Groovy Postbuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

The Groovy Postbuild plugin is made to change the build result (*post*build).
The Groovy plugin is made to run simple Groovy scripts *inside* your job.

Answer (score -1):

Click `Manage Jenkins`-->`Script Console`

[image]

Comment: Does not answer the question.  The question is regarding the groovy postBuild plugin, not the script console